# Is there a way to modify an IOptionsSnapshot<T> programmatically instead of a change in the source file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a transient class registered in ASP.NET Core's DI.

An `IOptions<T>` is injected into its constructor. For every request and when needed, during runtime and based on a condition, I want to have another instance of `IOptions` injected.

Since `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` gets updated for every request when the source file gets updated, is there a way to mimic this behavior but instead of a change in the file, I want to programmatically make a change in `IOptions`, and before constructor injection, during runtime when a request comes in?

And use `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` instead of `IOptions<T>` for that.

**Update:**

Condition example to be run before injection happens somewhere in the app like maybe a controller or action custom attribute? In the attribute check a value and so:

```
if (some condition) 
    Options.cnnectionstring = "string1"; 
else
    Options.cnnectionstring = "string2";
```

**Injected into a class like this:**

```
public class Books
{
    private readonly string connectionString;
    
    public Books(IOptions<DBOptions> options)
    {
        this.connectionString = options.Value.connectionString;
    }
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ....  //uses connectionString
    }
}
```

**Registered like this:**

```
services.Configure<DBOptions>(options =>
{
    options.connectionString = "some connection string";
});
```

Comment: Can you show how is configured the service and injected in controller?

Comment: I might not understand. But you can register it manually. `AddTransient<IOptions<MyModel>>(provider =>
                {
     var config = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
     // do manual check on config.

     // Return your custom model
                    return Options.Create(new MyModel());
    })`

Comment: `during runtime and based on a condition`. Can you explicit the condition?

Comment: @vernou. See the update above. Basic standard registration and constructor injection.

Comment: Sure, just create an in memory IConfigurationProvider and register it in your `Main` using `ConfigurationBuilder.Add(IConfigurationSource)`.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich, can you specify the condition? What resource need? Does it need some information from the HTTP request?

Comment: @vernou The condition is coming from the UI and will be part of the request. The condition is a minor detail. Modifying the options object before being injected is what I care about.

Answer (score 1):

[IOption (like IConfiguration) is registered as singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#options-interfaces-1), but the request is scoped. Then it isn't possible to use request's information to modify the configuration.

You can use a intermediate **scoped** service, that retrieve the request's information and generate the desired connection string, like :

```cs
public class BooksConnectionString
{
    public IConfiguration _configuration;
    public IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public BooksConnectionString(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            var library = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["library"].First();
            return _configuration.GetConnectionString(library);
        }
    }
}
```

Register the service as scoped :

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<BooksConnectionString>();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can inject like :

```cs
public class Books
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public Books(BooksConnectionString options)
    {
        this.connectionString = BooksConnectionString.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

It's suppose you can modify the class where the connection string is injected. If you can't modify this class, then you can register IOption as scoped :

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<IOptions<DBOptions>>(p =>
        {
            var configuration = p.GetService<IConfiguration>();
            var httpContextAccessor = p.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var library = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["library"].First();
            var dbOptions = configuration.GetSection("Databases").GetSection(library).Get<DBOptions>();
            return Options.Create(dbOptions);
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

**Warning, IOption are expected as singleton. Register IOption as scoped would break this expectation. To be used as a last resort.**

Comment: `IOptionsSnapshot<DBOptions>` are registered as scoped, I think for this purpose. That might be a better option here?

Comment: @ajbeaven, Maybe, but this need to modify the controller. So I recommend the first solution and inject directly `BooksConnectionString` service. Declare `IOption` as scoped is only when it isn't possible to modify the controller's dependencies.